# How can I calculate the slope from a linear regression analysis?

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to overlay an abline onto a plot, the result of linear regression. I want to create a scatter plot showing 
`TrainRegRpt$train.data.Price` (original price) on the x-axis,
`TrainRegress$fitted.values` (the projected price that came from the lm model) on the y-axis and draw the line of best fit through the plotted points.

Here is some of my code:

```
TrainRegress <- lm(PriceBH.df$Price ~ ., data=PriceBH.df, subset = train.rows)
TrainRegRpt  <- data.frame(train.data$Price, TrainRegress$fitted.values, TrainRegress$residuals)
x <- as.vector(TrainRegRpt$TrainRegress.fitted.values)    # on the x-axis
y <- as.vector(TrainRegRpt$train.data.Price)     #on the y-axis
plot(TrainRegRpt$train.data.Price ~ TrainRegRpt$TrainRegress.fitted.values)
abline(x,y)
```

The scatter plot came out the same:

```
x <- as.vector(newdf$fv)
y <- as.vector(newdf$p)
p <-as.vector(TrainRegRpt$train.data.Price) # my y-axis in the scatter plot
fv <- as.vector(round(TrainRegRpt$TrainRegress.fitted.values,2) # my y-axis in the scatter plot
newdf<- dfrm <- data.frame(p,fv)
plot(newdf$p ~ newdf$fv)
abline(x,y)
summary(TrainRegress)
```

The following is the summary of TrainRegress: Coefficients obtained from the summary of TrainRegress:

```
Intercept  Estimate     
................30.318
CRIM.........0.245
CHAS......5.8368
RM..........8.4846
```

I extracted the y-intercept as follows:

```
y.interceptval <-summary(TrainRegress)$coefficients[1]
```

I will use `y.interceptval` in the `abline(y.interceptval,***?slope***)` but I need to know how to calculate the slope. How do I calculate the slope to pass to `abline(y.interceptval, slope)`?

I have 5 textbooks here that are no help and my professor refuses to help me and I really want this to be perfect!
Thank you!!!

```
plot(TrainRegRpt$train.data.Price ~ TrainRegRpt$TrainRegress.fitted.values)<br>
abline(x,y)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Hi Andrea, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide a reproducible example with code that can be run by others. One step towards this is to provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(TrainRegRpt[1:20,])`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: Hi Ian, I provided code, is that not enough? How much of my code should I include? From reading in the data file? Including the splitting of records into training and validation? I just included the ln() function I ran and the results I based the rest of my code off of, I am new at this so any guidance you can offer would be great!

Comment: The problem isn't that we don't have access to your code, it's that we can't *run* your code because we don't have the required data objects. For example I can't run your `lm` call because I don't have `PriceBH.df`.  I can't run your scatter plot because I don't have access to `newdf`. Sometimes providing the data isn't feasible, so an alternative approach is to make simulated data that matches your data closely enough that we can run your code. This is covered in the first answer to the question in link I provided above. In sum, to be able to help, we should be able to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already calculated your slope. The slopes from a linear regression analysis using `lm()` are the coefficients. So, in this case, `30.318` is your Y-intercept.

This gives you a regression equation of:

```
Y = 30.318 + 0.245*(CRIM) + 5.8368*(CHAS) + 8.4846*(RM)
```

The numbers `0.245`, `5.8368`, and `8.4846` are the coefficients for each variable and they are also the individual slopes.

Also, one thing about your fitted vs reesiduals plot, it looks like you reversed the way `abline()` is supposed to be (i.e. instead of `abline(x,y)` it should be `abline(y,x)`.

**Edit** You used `abline(x,y)` but your plotted data are

`plot(TrainRegRpt$train.data.Price ~ TrainRegRpt$TrainRegress.fitted.values)`

(`train.data.Price` vs. `Fitted Values` not `x` vs `y`).